# Multilingual app include translation dll in exe file

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, multilingual, resx

I have a multilingual application, the default language is mine, and I've translated it to en-US. Now it has a dll file under *..Debug\en-US\programname.resources.dll* and I've noticed that the program failes to load the translations, if this dll is not in the en-US folder next to the executable file. Is there a way to include this dll in the exe file, so it doesn't need to be around, and still be able to modifie the resx files with the translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows can load language-related resources for EXE in several ways, from corresponding language folder\file, from corresponding DLL file in same folder or by choosing corresponding resources inside of exe. Many localization tools do what you want, for example [sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com) can create translated versions of EXE by replacing corresponding resources inside. But i am not sure about digital signing of such EXE, probably it should be signed after translation (because changing of resources can broke sign).